# Does the info page work differently on Programmers and other SE sites?

Tags: support, site-attributes

I have been a member of a number of SE sites for some time, but have only today joined the Programmers site. I have asked one question, and have been keeping an eye on responses. My info page appears to be giving incorrect information, attributing my question to users that have not answered or commented on my question. An example is shown below - keppla has not (as far as I can tell) been involved in this question at all. Viewing my info page at other times has shown the same problem, but involving different users.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

keppla was the most recent user to add an answer, but then they deleted it.

This means that the answer won't be visible (unless you have >10K reputation) but the user is marked as the most recent contributor to the thread.

This is the same behaviour on all sites in the network.

Comment: I've obviously not noted this particular behaviour on other sites. Thanks.

Comment: On SO (for example) the chance of you noticing that the last answer has been deleted is smaller as the volume of questions is higher so you're less likely to see it and it's more likely that someone else has come along and provided a subsequent answer.